# SwfitUI-Value of type '[Course]' has no member 'identified'

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am developing iphone app using xcode 11 beta 5.
but I found the error like "Value of type '[Course]' has no member 'identified'"

This is my source code.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List(
                [
                    Course.init(name: "sample1", imageUrl: "no image"),
                    Course.init(name: "sample2", imageUrl: "no image")
                ].identified(by: \.name)
            ){
                Text($0.name)
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Courses"))
        }
    }
}
```

how can i solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is fixed variant

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List(
                [
                    Course(name: "sample1", imageUrl: "no image"),
                    Course(name: "sample2", imageUrl: "no image")
                ], id: \.name        // << here !!
            ){
                Text($0.name)
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Courses"))
        }
    }
}
```